# Web Essentials 2015 JavaScript source map not generated

Tags: visual-studio-2015, web-essentials

Web Essentials is supposed to automatically generate source map files for JavaScript minified files as stated [here on the project website](http://vswebessentials.com/features/javascript#source-maps).

However, for my minified files, I find only the *sourcename.min.js* file.
The web site states that the option should be in *Tools/Options*, however I can't seem to find any related toggle to enable that feature under the Web Essentials node.

What am I missing here? Is there any work-around to enable the feature?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want has been moved into the "Bundler and Compiler" extension.  Although you are correct in that the Web Essentials project website says map files can be generated, I think the site is out of date.  Check out what is said at https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ec27da7-e24b-4d56-8064-fd7e88ac1c40 where they talk about map files.  It does say they're supposed to be autogenerated, but for my concerns (I wanted CSS map files generated) I had to modify the bundleconfig.json as described at the bottom of that page.

Comment: i have this extension as well, what modification did you exactly do to obtain maps?

Comment: The bundleconfig.json file was added for me automatically, either when I installed the extension or when I compiled - I'm not sure.  However, upon opening that file, I found it configured to compile two LESS files; one that I wanted, the other not. I removed the latter and added the properties to minify and map the former.  i.e.

[
  {
    "outputFile": "Content/less/main.css",
    "inputFile": "Content/less/main.less",
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "options": {
      "sourceMap": true
    }
  }
]

Comment: Interestingly, the Bundler and Compiler page says that mapping is only for javascript, yet that too is out of date as it's definitely mapping CSS files, for me.

Comment: so the part that did it is "options": { "sourceMap": true }. right?

Comment: Yes, that's what did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

To enable source maps, add this property to the bundleconfig.json file:

```
"sourceMap": true
```

It says here in this link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier, under Source maps section.